# Player not moving smoothly in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I made this game in pygame and I want the player to move and it moves but not in the way I want it.It kinda teleports and then goes back to walking normally and then it teleports again and so on.

This is the code by now:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,1000))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


playerX = 100
playerY = 100

def ecranAlb():
    WHITE = [255,255,255]
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    
def player():
    global playerX, playerY
    playerImg = pygame.image.load('knight.png')
    playerImg = pygame.transform.scale(playerImg,(250,150))
    screen.blit(playerImg,(playerX,playerY))
    
    vel = 10

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerX -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerX += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        playerY -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        playerY += vel





running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    ecranAlb()
    player()
    clock.tick(200)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not load the image in the `player` function. `pygame.image.load` causes the lag, as it is very time consuming. Load the image once during  initialization and us the loaded image inside the function.

Ensure that the image *Surface* has the same format as the display *Surface*. Use [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) (or [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha)) to create a *Surface* that has the same pixel format. This improves performance when the image is `blit` on  the display, because the formats are compatible and `blit` does not need to perform an implicit transformation.

```py
playerImg = pygame.image.load('knight.png').convert_alpha()
playerImg = pygame.transform.scale(playerImg,(250,150))
vel = 10

def player():
    global playerX, playerY
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerX -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerX += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        playerY -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        playerY += vel

    screen.blit(playerImg,(playerX,playerY))
```

Comment: you sure this is right cuz it's not working

Comment: @DavidMustea Yes I am. What does it mean "it's not working"?

Comment: I tried to do myself it and it wasn't working so I decided to copy paste your response, and still, isn't working

Comment: It's the same problem, the player is teleporting (not moving smoothly, he is not 100% teleporting)

Comment: @DavidMustea I cannot reproduce the issue. The issue seems to be related to your system or IDE